# Swift syntax for MagicalRecord saveWithBlock

Tags: swift, core-data, objective-c-blocks, magicalrecord

In objC the way to saveWithBlock is

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        // This block runs in background thread
        } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        // This block runs in main thread
        }];
```

For the life of me, I cannot get the right Swift block/closure syntax correct. Don't know why this isn't sinking in with me. Could someone lend a hand and produce the swift version of above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should look something like this: off the top of my head...

```
MagicalRecord.saveWithBlock({ (localContext : NSManagedObjectContext!) in
        // This block runs in background thread
    }, completion: { (success : Bool, error : NSError!) in
       // This block runs in main thread
    })
```

Comment: Hey Mark, I tried that but get a syntax error "Extra argument "completion" in call. :(

Comment: i've seen blocks show complier errors!... try adding at least two lines of code in your block... i.e println("whatever') and then your actual code on another line...

Comment: Added two lines of code for both background and completion. Still the same syntax error. Arrrg

Comment: The signature of the second block should be `(success : Bool, error : NSError!)`

Comment: Martin, I did change it to Bool but didn't add the "!" to NSError. Having said that...the error is still the same. Thanks for the correction

Comment: @Stuville: ... and `(localContext : NSManagedObjectContext!)`

Comment: @Mark: What could be the reason why it doesn't save using this method ?

Comment: I still have an error: **Cannot convert value of type** `'(Bool, NSError!) -> ()'` **to expected argument type** `'MRSaveCompletionHandler?'`

Comment: I was getting the same error as Fisherman, but found that this worked. 
MagicalRecord.saveWithBlock({ (localContext: NSManagedObjectContext!) in
}, completion: { (MRSaveCompletionHandler) in
})

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3.0 and MagicalRecord 2.3.2

```
 MagicalRecord.saveWithBlock({
    (localContext: NSManagedObjectContext!) in
// Do your work to be saved here, against the `localContext` instance
// Everything you do in this block will occur on a background thread

}, completion: {
    (MRSaveCompletionHandler) in
    // This block runs in main thread
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
  MagicalRecord.save({ (localContext:NSManagedObjectContext) in   
    }, completion:{  (success: Bool,error: NSError!) in

        } as? MRSaveCompletionHandler
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift4 syntax is given below, try this

```
MagicalRecord.save({ (localContext) in
    // This block runs in background thread
}) { (success, error) in
    // This block runs in main thread
}
```

Hope its helpful.